# Reading numbers from file into a vector of vector of vertices

Tags: c++, file-io, vector

So I'm trying to read a text file (of unknown size) into a vector of vectors that are of my own defined type: `Vertex` (contains float x,y,z). So when all is said and done, each "row" in `coordpts` (variable for my vector of vectors) should represent a face of the object being read in and therefore should have several sets of xyz coordinates.

I'm working on the premise that each line in the file being read in represents a single face (of a cube, teapot, whatever object).

I know I should push back each set of three coordinates into a temporary vector, and then push that temporary vector back into `coordpts`, but I'm having trouble accessing the elements?

My code compiles when I do the above, but anytime I try to access an element I'm getting errors.

**Am I missing something obvious?**

I mostly just want to print out the data so that I can see if I've read it in correctly (also because I'll have to access it in other functions later on).

#### Header file:

```
#include <iostream> // Definitions for standard I/O routines.
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>    // Definitions for math library.
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Vertex {
public:
    Vertex() {};
    float x, y, z; // float to store single coordinate.
};

class Object : public Vertex {
public:
    Object() {};
    vector<vector<Vertex>> coordpts; // vector of x, y, z floats derived from vertex class.
    // vector<Vertex> coordpts;
};
```

#### Program file:

<sup>(I know main isn't there, I've included it in another file.)</sup>

```
#include "header.h" // Include header file.

Object object;
string inputfile;
fstream myfile;

void Raw::readFile() {
     vector<Vertex> temp;

    cout << "Enter the name of the file: ";
    cin >> inputfile;

    myfile.open(inputfile);

    if(myfile.is_open()) {
        while(myfile >> object.x >> object.y >> object.z) {
            temp.push_back(object);
            object.coordpts.push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    myfile.close();

    cout << object.coordpts[0] << endl;
};
```

Comment: Stating _"I'm getting errors"_ doesn't make up a valid question here. Post a [MCVE] please!

Comment: What's kind of error, Katie?

Comment: sorry, should have included that. When I try to access individually via object.coordpts[0].x, its a no member named 'x' in 'std::__1::vector<Vertex, std::__1::allocator<Vertex> >' (same for y and z).

Comment: There's some weird stuff going on here. You have a global `Object` which you repeatedly update and copy into a temporary which is later copied back into a member of the same `Object`. Why? And why does `Object` inherit from `Vertex` in the first place? And don't use globals. Ever.

Answer (score -1):

```
cout << object.coordpts[0] << endl;
```

Here you are trying to output the first element of your "vector of vectors of vertices", *e.g.*, you are trying to output a `std::vector<Vertex>`. This will result in an error as there is no overload for the output operator taking a vector of vertices.

> error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' and 'std::vector<Vertex>')

If you want to, *e.g.*, output the x-value of the first vertice in the first `std::vector` in `coordpts` then you must do something like this.

```
std::cout << object.coordpts[0][0].x << std::endl;
```

Or, you could simply create your own overload for outputting a `std::vector<Vertex>` row/face.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<Vertex>& face) {
    for (auto&& v : face) {
        out << v.x << " " << v.y << " " << v.z << std::endl;
    }
    return out;
}

/* ... */

std::cout << object.coordpts[0] << std::endl; // Ok, output first row/face.
```

See <kbd>[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a55733b42428f74a)</kbd> with modified syntax.

Comment: okay, but say I wanted to print out a whole row (a face of some object being read in). Like, if I'm reading in a file that has coordinates for a cube, there would be 12 individual items in a row, four groups of three coordinates each. Ideal output would be like '[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]'...Would I do that by creating my own overload, like you said above?

Comment: @Katie Yes, you can do that with, _e.g._, a custom overload of the `<<` operator. See the live example link.